# How to identify and remove observations with ValueError in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

While working on a dataset with pandas I am getting **ValueError**

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: <some_string>
```

I want identify and remove such observations from my data set and I am unable to find a way to do it. Please suggest.

The code that I am running :

```
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_final)
```

Edit 1 : After searching online and looking at some other posts in SO, I have understood that this might be happening because there is some column/s in my data which is supposed to have numbers/floats but contains string in some observations. How can I identify such columns?

Comment: You should also provide sample data and expected outcome.  What you've provided is insufficient.

Comment: @piRSquared - The problem is I don't know what will be the sample data for this issue, since I am unable to figure out where in my data is the issue residing. 

I am running the above command and getting some error, but I don't know how or due to what is that error coming.

Comment: What about the data you are using?  If you feel it is too large, find a subset that still produces the error.  This takes effort from you.  But it is effort better spent by you than less efficient effort from others trying guess at what your error is.  Once you've identified a small enough sample that produces the error, share the data.  Copy and paste the data into this post.